# PHP $row to array

Tags: php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

At the moment my $row['content'] has four strings inside it, how can I get them into seperate objects in an array?

As in 0 > "first string"

1 > "second string"
etc...

At the moment they are all bundled into one it seems... But I need them seperated in an array.

I am new to PHP and have spent ages trying to find out how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

```
print_r ($row['content']);
```

Returns:

```
hello world!another oneand another one...more coming...
```

var dump of $row returns:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    [1]=> string(12) "hello world!" 
    ["content"]=> string(12) "hello world!" 
} array(4) { 
    [0]=> string(1) "2" 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
    [1]=> string(11) "another one" 
    ["content"]=> string(11) "another one" 
} array(4) {
    [0]=> string(1) "3" 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "3" 
    [1]=> string(18) "and another one..." 
    ["content"]=> string(18) "and another one..." 
} array(4) {
    [0]=> string(1) "4" 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "4" 
    [1]=> string(14) "more coming..." 
    ["content"]=> string(14)
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($row)` show?

Comment: `explode("\n", $row['contents'])`?

Comment: Would you please add some information about your db schema?

Comment: what is the separator of these 4 strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TRY

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $output[] = $row['content'];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
```

Comment: there are no separators at all, that's the prob I think. Cheers.

Comment: without separator how do you distinguish that there are 4 string??

Comment: because it's pulled from a database where I have four separate entries, it's bundled them together for some reason.

Comment: which mySQL function you use to build them while retrieving? `CONCAT`

Comment: there should be, may be space

Comment: then use [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) and put some separator. and again use that separator to cut it off

Comment: I used: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table", $con);

Comment: means there are 4 diffrent `rows`  not 4 columns

Comment: there are two columns in the table, ID and content.

Comment: you didnt mention all these in your question. I have updated my answer. see now.

Comment: diEcho you're a genius, but I need 15 rep to upvote, you're answer is perfect though. Cheers mate!

Answer (score -3):

EDIT: I read it wrong, sorry. If your strings are seperated by a comma then this will suffice:

```
$array = explode(',', $row['content']);
```

Comment: @diEcho: You're right, i'm sorry.

Can you give some more info on how the data is put in the database? This problem is only solved (i think) when we know what kind of data there is. If you, as a human being, can't separate the strings, than sure as hell a computer can't :)